# PHP form does not submit after adding condition

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am creating a form  input which the minimum amount for submitting is 700. Any values more than 700 should be taken as extra savings. It should save 700 as amount and the excess as extra saving. The form is working fine for values greater than 700 showing that my code works but it does not submit for input that is exactly 700.

```
   $extra_savings = 0;


   if ($amount_saved > 700) {
        $extra_savings = $amount_saved - 700;
        $amount_saved = 700;
    }

    // validate input
    $valid = true;
    if (empty($amount_saved)):
        $amount_savedError = 'Please enter amount saved';
        $valid = false;
    elseif ($amount_saved < 700):
            $amount_savedError = 'Amount Saved Should be 700 or more';
            $valid = false; 
    else:
        $valid = true;
    endif;
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: `if ($amount_saved > 700) {` says lmore than 700, but 700 is allowed. So >= is wat you need

Comment: btw: See that you can put that value 700 in a constant: next year some one wants to change it to 750 and you have to check all your scripts to replace the value

Comment: Good point on the constant. Is there any problem on the validation conditions? I think that's why the validation is not passing.

Comment: The problem was on another validation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use greater than or eqaul to , use this

```
$extra_savings = 0;


   if ($amount_saved >= 700) {
        $extra_savings = $amount_saved - 700;
        $amount_saved = 700;
    }

    // validate input
    $valid = true;
    if (empty($amount_saved)):
        $amount_savedError = 'Please enter amount saved';
        $valid = false;
    elseif ($amount_saved < 700):
            $amount_savedError = 'Amount Saved Should be 700 or more';
            $valid = false; 
    else:
        $valid = true;
    endif;
```

Comment: I was talking about the validation. Something is making the validation false when user inputs 700

Comment: I had an amount saved validation below that. That is where the problem was.